# Travel to Ireland and the UK 3 weeks before passport expiration

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, ireland

My USA passport expires two weeks after my planned return from a one week trip. The trip starts in Chicago and lands in Dublin, Ireland we stay for three days and take a domestic flight to the UK. Will I have a problem at immigration?

Comment: The question is more specific and not really a duplicate…

Comment: @Relaxed in fact, the [IATA module](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/IE-Ireland-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) to determine whether you have the right documents (passport, visa, ...) says it is fine with a passport expiring less than 10 days after leaving Ireland. The link I used seemed to be more an opportunity to sell expedited passport service. As Ireland and UK belong both to the Common Travel Area, the rules are likely to be similar.

Comment: Other related resource: the [wikipedia page about Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area#Identification_requirements) lists some domestic travel valid documents, a valid passport is enough.

Answer (score 2):

> My USA passport expires **two weeks after my planned return** from a one week trip.

I understand this to mean your passport is valid during your trip.

As long as the midnight has not passed on the expiry date, your passport is valid and you will have no problems entering the country.

Even if by chance you extend your trip and your passport expires, the US embassy can grant you an emergency passport to return.

As far as entry to Dublin is concerned, as [US citizens do not need a visa](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/visa_requirements_for_entering_ireland.html) your passport is only used as proof of your citizenship.

For your trip to the UK, you [do not need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism) (unless you have been previously denied entry) so you should not have any problems there either.

Of course, for travel *within the US* you only need to show government issued identification and you don't require a passport at all.

Comment: Even if he does not need a visa, countries have still been known to require a passport with 3 (or 6) months of validity in order to let foreigners _enter_. I don't know if the UK or Ireland are among those countries, though.

Comment: The UK has no such restrictions as far as I know.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to answer the question, which is not about visa requirements but about the validity of identity documents.